# Open A Vcard Using Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, vcf-vcard

I am trying to open a vcard using Selenium.  The vcard uses a javacript command instead of a traditional link:

http://www.allenmatkins.com/Professionals/Ahern-William/Biography.aspx

```
<a id="ctl00_phContent_content_0_hlVcard" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$phContent$content_0$hlVcard','')">Vcard</a>

**(from http://www.allenmatkins.com/Professionals/Ahern-William/Biography.aspx)
```

B/c of the javascript, I chose to use Selenium to open the link:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
element = driver.find_element_by_link_text("Vcard")
element.click()
```

When I run the above code, I get a popup (from outlook), that asks me where I would like to save the text.

I am trying to find a way to open the link as plain text.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Great question. The way you can do this would be you can download the vcard into a folder of your project. Then parse through the vcf file. Found a great API which can do this. Here is the link to the same [ReadingVcard](http://code.google.com/p/ez-vcard/wiki/ReadingVCards#2.1_VCardReader). I will post some sample code to parse through the vcard. If you download the file and open it in a notepad you will get all the info from the vcard. we can retrieve all the info using the api. Let me know if you require more clarification.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
        File file = new File("William-R.-Ahern.vcf");
        VCard vcard = Ezvcard.parse(file).first();
        System.out.println(vcard.getFormattedName().getValue());
        System.out.println(vcard.getEmails().get(0).getValue());
        System.out.println(vcard.getTitles().get(0).getValue());
        System.out.println(vcard.getTelephoneNumbers().get(0).getText());
        System.out.println(vcard.getTelephoneNumbers().get(1).getText());
        System.out.println(vcard.getAddresses().get(0).getStreetAddress());
        System.out.println(vcard.getAddresses().get(0).getLocality());
        System.out.println(vcard.getAddresses().get(0).getRegion());
        System.out.println(vcard.getAddresses().get(0).getPostalCode());
        System.out.println(vcard.getAddresses().get(0).getCountry());

    }
```

Comment: Hey Vinay, thanks for the quick response.  My problem isn't so much with parsing the vcard, but the actual process of getting the vcard.  B/c of the pop up, I cant get the text.  Is there a way to circumvent the pop up, and just get the text (preferably using driver.page_source) in Selenium?

Comment: What is the browser you are using? If it is firefox then you can override the settings through java code in such a way that the file will be downloaded automatically to the specified location without the pop up.

Comment: Yup, using Firefox.  Is there a way to do it with Python instead of Java?

Comment: @NeilAggarwal Sorry mate I am more of a java guy and not much into python. But the settings is for firefox and not parse java or python. This should help you <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656056/file-download-dialog-in-firefox>